# Where is the mistake in this set-theoretic argument?

Tags: functions, elementary-set-theory, ordinals

Let $\omega$ be the first infinite ordinal and for all $n\in \omega $ define $n=\{0,1,2,...,n-1\}$. In particular, $2=\{0,1\}$.

Let  $f:\omega\rightarrow \omega$, $f(x)=x^2 $.

Now $4=f(2)=f(\{0,1\})=\{n\in \omega:\exists x\in \{0,1\}, f(x)=n\}=\{f(0),f(1)\}=\{0,1\}$.

But $4\neq \{0,1\}$.

Comment: The phrase *"for all $n \in \omega$ define $n = \{0, 1, 2, \dots, n-1\}$"* makes no sense: if $n \in \omega$ you cannot redefine it to be a set, it is already defined. You should have said: *"for all $n \in \omega$ define $\bar n = \{0, 1, 2, \dots, n-1\}$"*, and thus any confusion would have become impossible.

Comment: @Alex: While the formulation is a bit off, the finite ordinals $n$ *do* satisfy the equality $n=\{0,\ldots,n-1\}$. They are already sets. This is set theory. Everything is a set.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing two meanings of $f(x)$.

1. It could be the unique $y$ such that $\langle x,y\rangle\in f$
2. It could be $\{f(u)\mid u\in x\}$.

This is why in the context of set theory (where everything is a set), the latter is often denoted by $f[x]$ or $f"x$.

Comment: That's "$f$ <closing double quote> $x$"? I've never seen that before!

Comment: It is a very common notation in set theory. Sometimes $f''x$ instead, depending on whether or not you are using $'$ in your notation. Probably because you cannot possibly confuse it with $f(x)$ under any circumstances (whereas $f[x]$ can be mistaken for $f(x)$ when writing on a blackboard, for example).

Comment: Then  $f[2]=f[\{0,1\}]=\{0,1\}$ and $f(2)=f(\{0,1\})=4$

Comment: @user198613: Yes.